# Flutter not rendering color for transparent background png icon

Tags: flutter

As I am very much new to the front-end world, I am not sure when I download the png from flaticon website such as https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/telescope_3480961?related_id=3480961&origin=search I see telescope with colors, but when I use it with in Flutter using `ImageIcon`

```
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
          child: const ImageIcon(
            AssetImage('assets/images/telescope.png'),
            size: 150,
          ),
        ),
```

The image shows entirely black. I understand this png has a transparent background but why is Flutter not rendering the colours that came with the png? I am sure I am making a mistake but not sure how to resolve this.

The icon is looking like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show and image from your assets you need `Image.asset`, so instead of `ImageIcon`, use `Image.asset`:

```
child: Image.asset(
  'assets/images/telescope.png',
   height: 150,
   width: 150,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use assets image using `Image.asset` widget like this just remove `ImageIcon` widget from your code. also make sure you added `assets path` in `pubsec.yaml` file.

```
Container(
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/telescope.png'),
 )
```

Assets path in `pubspec.yaml` file

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```